# How to sum array values more than 15 digits using array_sum in php

Tags: php

I have to sum values of an array. I have an array

`$arr = array('0' => 87.85749999999999823, '1'=>1);
print_r(array_sum($arr));`

And I am getting output as 88.8575, but I am expecting as 88.85749999999999823

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure, but this could be down to floating point errors that occur in a few languages

Answer (score 2):

the `float` is limited at 14 digit. if you need more accuracy, try the BC Math library

```
<?php
echo "<br/>float<br/>";
$arr = array('0' => 87.85749999999999823, '1'=>1);
print_r(($arr));
print_r(bcadd($arr[0], $arr[1], 20));

echo "<br/>BCMath<br/>";
$arr = array('0' => "87.85749999999999823", '1'=>"1");
print_r(($arr));
print_r(bcadd($arr[0], $arr[1], 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use as below :

```
<?php
$arr = array('0' => '87.85749999999999823', '1'=>'1');
$res = 0.0;
foreach($arr as $val){
    $res = bcadd($res, $val, 20);
}
echo $res;
```